# How to get height of area top of safe area with Flutter

Tags: android, iphone, flutter, height

I have a rounded corner mobile phone.
The top part of the phone have the front camera and power icons etc.

I want to get this area height for my Flutter application.

I tried

```
MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top
```

But this always return 0

I also tried

```
MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding
```

it also return EdgeInsets.zero

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var safePadding = MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding;
    print("Safe $safePadding");

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: _buildVideoContent(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Can someone provide some advice to get this height value?

*The reason I want to get this height is; I have an image in the application which can be scaled up using `Transform.scale`. When I scale the image bigger than the screen size the image appear under this area. So I need a way to cover it.*

[image]

Comment: Please specify in more detailed description on why you want to calculate this height? If you want to add padding or want or UI to be rendered below that part, Try Using SafeArea Widget. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64873410/how-to-get-status-bar-height-in-flutter

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58150

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Height of the status bar always returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62943238/height-of-the-status-bar-always-returns-0)

Comment: @Prashant the reason I want to get this height is; I have an image in the application which can be scaled up using Transform.scale. When I scale the image bigger than the screen size the image appear under this area. So I need a way to cover it

Answer (score -1):

Try using **kToolBarHeight** property
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/toolbarHeight.html

Answer (score -1):

if you want to get status bar height, you can write

```
double height = MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.top;
```

If you want appBar height

```
double appBarHeight = AppBar().preferredSize.height;
```

Comment: Even though that's the way to get safe area height, the question says that viedpadding.top returns 0. Did you read the question?